# Migrate from JSF 1.0 to 1.2: class file for javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.JspIdConsumer not found

Tags: jsf, tomcat, jstl, jsf-1.2

I am trying to migrate a web project (Eclipse, Tomcat 6, building with Java 1.6) from JSF 1.0 to JSF 1.2 - don't you dare to mention JSF 2.0 or greater. ;)

I downloaded jsf-api_1.2.jar and jstl_1.2.jar. I renamed them after the original libraries (jsf-api.jar and jstl.jar) and replaced the original libraries in the folder where ANT would get these libraries and build the runtime.

When I try to build, I would get:

```
[javac] /users/somePath/ch/somePackage/MyCustomTag.java:23: cannot access javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.JspIdConsumer
[javac] class file for javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.JspIdConsumer not found
[javac] public class MyCustomTag extends CommandLinkTag  {
[javac]        ^
```

I don't really understand this compile-error since I searched through the original jsf-api.jar and jstl.jar where I couldn't find such a class. I can't see why it is suddenly missing.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I was missing jsf-impl_1.2.jar.